# Need help with Oibaf video drivers

Tags: nvidia, graphics, ppa, additional-drivers

My machine is using the Nouveau driver for an Nvidia GT218.  I've already had problems using a proprietary driver under 16.04 LTS.  I've read the Oibaf PPA offers an improved open source driver.

Even though I've added the Oibaf PPA, I don't understand how to access the driver.  I see the Oibaf PPA in the Other Software tab of Software & Updates.  I do not see another open source driver available in the Additional Drivers tab, only Nouveau.

I'd have preferred to add the PPA using the GUI, but the first several articles I found all referenced using the terminal, so I followed those steps including 'sudo apt-get update' at the end.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: go  `sudo apt upgrade` , then reboot. If the xserver nouveau driver upgrade works better  you're in luck, if not then too bad. ( there won't be anything for you to manually add in Additional Drivers, it's just an xserver driver upgrade.

Comment: You should not need a ppa. Your card now uses the legacy drive 340.xx which is in the Ubuntu standard repository. Updated driver search by nVidia model, do not download, just check correct driver version
http://www.geforce.com/drivers